# How to delete Poly3DCollection object in matplotlib python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, axes

The code below creates and plots three 3d-polygons. In the dictionary `polygon_dict`, the label for each `Poly3DCollection` artist is created and saved. The goal is to refer to a particular polygon using its label and then delete it from the plot. My failed attempt to achieve this (it only works for `ax.plot()` objects) is shown commented at the end. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

polygon_dict = {}
polygon_count = 0

def plot_polygon(vertices):
    global polygon_count
    polygon_count += 1
    polygon_label = 'P' + str(polygon_count)
    polygon_dict[polygon_label] = ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([vertices]))

[plot_polygon(np.random.rand(3,3)) for i in range(3)]
print(polygon_dict)
plt.show()

# Delete polygon with label 'P2'. The following doesn't work.
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# polygon_dict['P2'].pop(0)
# plt.show()
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# The resulting plot should not have polygon 'P2'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [remove artists](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove.html):

```
...
print(polygon_dict)
polygon_dict["P2"].remove()
plt.show()
```

As polygon `P2` is still referenced in your dictionary, it will not be garbage-collected and continue to exist as a Poly3DCollection object. Therefore, it is not substantially different from

```
....
print(polygon_dict)
polygon_dict["P2"].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```